# url encoding in java has issue with apostrophe and space

Tags: java

I have the lastname as "Mc' Donald" and I am trying to encode in such a way that it works. Like the encoded value at the end should have %27+ for apostrophe and space. With this code, it is encoding to "%2527". in db, I have Mc' Donald so I am replacing first to encode the whole thing in the next line.

```
lastName = lastName.replace("&apos;", "'");
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(getHttpHeaders());
UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(baseUrl + "/idsearch").queryParam("lastname", URLEncoder.encode(lastName, "UTF-8")).queryParam("dateOfBirth", birthday);
 ResponseEntity<Response> result = restTemplate.exchange(uriBuilder.toUriString(),
                    HttpMethod.GET, entity, Response.class);
```

How do I get the code to work by encoding apostrophe and space to %27+ or %27%20?

Comment: Isn't there an error in your data? `%25` is `%`.. aren't you messing up the encoding somewhere?

Comment: Dropout - I modified the question. Can you check again pleasE?

Comment: I think its encoding the % in %27 again in uriBuilder.toUriString()

Comment: You're double encoding stuff somewhere..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do URL-encoding for values supplied to `UriComponentsBuilder.queryParam` method. It already knows to URL-encode your queryParam

Just do this:

```
lastName = lastName.replace("&apos;", "'");
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(getHttpHeaders());
UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(baseUrl + "/idsearch").queryParam("lastname",lastName).queryParam("dateOfBirth", birthday);
 ResponseEntity<Response> result = restTemplate.exchange(uriBuilder.toUriString(),
                    HttpMethod.GET, entity, Response.class);
```

Comment: After the uriBuilder.toUriString(), value is ?lastname=Mc'%20Donald&dateOfBirth=1986-05-09. Not sure why its not encoding '..

Comment: and what's wrong with that? it's encoding the space

Comment: but not the apostrophe

Comment: Because apostrophe is not mandatory to encode - it can be passed as is in URL query parameters. It only encodes the characters that must be encoded. Check JavaDoc of UriComponentBuilder.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html#queryParam-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...- says "encoding, if applied, will only encode characters that are illegal in a query parameter name or value such as "=" or "&". All others that are legal as per syntax rules in RFC 3986 are not encoded"